# Can I tweak all red text to bold in gnome-terminal

Tags: terminal, colors, gnome-terminal

Some **red** text output with git or autojump, are hard to see. I want it become **bold**. Maybe we can tweak some ansi color code?

In the screen-shot below, all bold red text comes from my script. the "j" is autojump's command.

[image: screenshot]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found the solution about git one. modify in ~/.gitconfig.

```
[color "status"]
    changed = blue normal bold
    added = green bold
    deleted = red bold
    untracked = magenta bold
```

To autojump output, I can make a alias or script to deal with.

addition:

After search, I found detail introduce here, hope can help others. https://gist.github.com/rab/4067067

```
[color "diff"]
    new = blue bold
    old = red bold
    frag = magenta bold
    meta = green reverse
```

Comment: It is already a shell function.  You could just fix it.  Create a follow-up issue for https://github.com/wting/autojump/issues/377 asking for the colour red not to be hardwired.

Comment: sure. I had added sth.

Answer (score -1):

You can rewrite that text by passing it through a pipe that would add bold escape with red escapes.
You can also modify gnome-terminal source to suit your needs.
There's no option or setting that would accomplish what you describe.

Comment: I had found https://git-scm.com/docs/git-config, It says "The accepted attributes are bold, dim, ul, blink, reverse, italic...." in color segment.